# Setzt man Fremdwörter und deren Übersetzung in Anführungszeichen?

Tags: translation, quotes, scientific-language

Wikipedia [schreibt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_(Internet)):

> Mashup (von englisch to mash für vermischen)...

Ich habe als Korrekturvorschlag bekommen beide Begriffe in Anführungszeichen zu setzen, also

> Mashup (von englisch „to mash“ für „vermischen“)

**Gibt es feste Regeln oder ist das weitgehend Geschmackssache?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In den [offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) betreffen die Paragraphen 89 bis 95 Anführungszeichen.

- § 89 lautet:

  > Mit Anführungszeichen schließt man etwas wörtlich Wiedergegebenes ein.

  Das trifft hier nicht zu.
- §§ 90–93 regeln Details zur wörtlichen Wiedergabe.
- § 94 regelt (Hervorhebung von mir):

  > Mit Anführungszeichen **kann** man Wörter oder Teile innerhalb eines Textes hervorheben und in bestimmten Fällen deutlich machen, dass man zu ihrer Verwendung Stellung nimmt, sich auf sie bezieht.

  Dies betrifft Deinen Fall, ist aber optional.
- § 95 regelt verschachtelte Anführungen.

Insofern verpflichtet Dich keine offizielle Regel, Anführungszeichen zu setzen, es ist aber ausdrücklich zugelassen. Um Verwirrung zu vermeiden, würde ich empfehlen, irgendeine Auszeichnung zu verwenden. Hier sind Anführungszeichen und Kursivschrift am üblichsten und auch typografisch am sinnvollsten. Ich würde Kursivschrift bevorzugen, da sie weniger störend ist; und so handhaben es auch die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln (Du bist also in guter Gesellschaft), zum Beispiel in § 65:

> Das Anredepronomen *Sie* und das entsprechende Possessivpronomen *Ihr* sowie die zugehörigen flektierten Formen schreibt man groß.

Comment: "Zu" "viele" "Anführungszeichen" in solchen "Texten" sehen oft gruslig aus und können auch "irreführend" sein - Sie werden oft als Ausdruck von Ironie oder Sarkasmus aufgefasst - Deshalb ist eine andere Art der Textauszeichnung, wie dein Vorschlag, kursiv zu setzen, viel besser.

Answer (score 9):

Da wissenschaftliche Arbeiten heutzutage nicht mehr mit der Schreibmaschine erstellt werden, würde ich dafür kursive Schrift bevorzugen und Anführungsstriche nur für wörtliche Rede und ggf. Zitate verwenden.

Also

> Mashup (von englisch *to mash* für *vermischen*)

Wenn es in deiner Arbeit nicht um sprachliche Aspekte geht, würde ich Hinweise auf die Wortherkunft oder Ähnliches weglassen.

> Mashup (englisch für *vermischen*)

Mit jeder Anmerkung störst du den Lesefluss, weswegen du sie möglichst kurz halten solltest.

Bei jedem Fremdwort, für das du eine Übersetzung angibst, solltest du dir auch überlegen, ob du es im Text nicht lieber ganz durch den deutschen Begriff ersetzen kannst. Wenn du hingegen doch etwas längere Erklärungen unterbringen möchtest, weil es sich beispielsweise um Fachbegriffe handelt, solltest du über die Erstellung eines Glossars nachdenken.

Comment: Ja, was man machen würde ist schon und gut. Gibt es hierfür aber feste Regeln, z.B. für wissenschaftliche Publikationen, wie es der Fall ist in anderen Sprachen? Es gibt sogar DIN-Normen für Geschäftsbriefe, also gibt es auch sowas für wissenschaftliche Publikationen?

Comment: @userunknown: Der erste Satz bezog sich auf eine ältere Version des Textes in einem anderen Beitrag. Da anscheinend der OP auch inzwischen die richtigen Anführungszeichen setzen kann, entferne ich den Satz.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Für die DIN-Norm der Geschäftsbriefe gibt es sogar eine LaTeX-Vorlage. ;) Die Verwendung der Norm ist aber freigestellt. Abgesehen davon, dass ein Geschäftsbrief wesentlich einfacher zu normieren ist, betreffen DIN-Normen in der Regel Prozesse oder Gegenstände aus der Geschäftswelt oder der Technik aber nicht der Wissenschaft. Wenn man nach Vorgaben für wissenschaftliche Arbeiten sucht, würde ich eher beim Fachbereich oder der Uni mal nachfragen. Sogar die verschiedenen Fachzeitschriften und -konferenzen haben aber noch nicht mal einheitliche Regeln.

Comment: @Clements   - Wissenschaftliche Fachzeitschriften haben eigentlich schon recht weitgehende Regeln, wie was geschrieben und gesetzt werden soll. Vielleicht nicht, was jeden Sonder- und Zweifelsfall angeht, aber so Dinge wie "was setzen wir kursiv?" sind eigentlich in den Redaktionsanweisungen, die man bekommt für seine Manuskripte, meistens schon enthalten...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich habe auch nicht behauptet, dass sie das nicht haben, sondern nur, dass das nicht einheitlich ist oder gar eine Norm existiert. Erstaunlicherweise vermuten hier anscheinend viele einheitliche Regeln, es gibt dazu aber hier noch keine Beiträge mit entsprechenden Regeln. Ich denke, hier tummeln sich genug Akademiker, von denen der ein oder andere über sowas ja schon gestolpert sein müsste. BTW.: Kannst du zukünftig meinen Namen bitte richtig schreiben? (Ist nicht persönlich gemeint. Die falsche Schreibweise tut mir nur in den Augen weh. ;-)

Comment: Es ist sogar so, dass die meisten wissenschaftlichen Zeitschriften diese Hausregeln hüten wie einen Schatz, denn die Erstellung hat Geld gekostet und das könnte einfach einer nehmen...

Answer (score 0):

Anführungsstriche sind Satzzeichen und die dienen der Abgrenzung:

- > Ich sah mir Kleidung im Geschäft an. (Vorgang)
- > Ich sah mir „Kleidung“ im Geschäft an. (Produktname)
- > Ich sah mir „Kleidung im Geschäft“ an. (Filmtitel).
- > Ich mag „Kinder“ mehr als „Milka“. (Herstellernamen)

Eine Formatierung (kursiv oder fett) ist selten gleichbedeutend mit korrekter Nutzung von Anführungsstrichen. [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anf%C3%BChrungszeichen) ist da gleich im ersten Satz sehr eindeutig (siehe Details in den Regeln). Geschmackssache ist fast unmöglich.

Comment: *im ersten Satz* – Welchen Satz meinst Du? Am besten zitierst Du ihn. — Beachte außerdem, dass das [die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/regeln-und-woerterverzeichnis/) Wörter, über die sie reden, grundsätzlich kursiv schreiben und somit fast gar keine Anführungszeichen verwenden (außer in Beispielen für Anführungszeichen).

Comment: Der erste Satz des verlinkten Artikels, das ist schon präzise. Kommentar etwas konfus - eine Enzyklopädie redet auch nicht. Auf dieser Internetseite gestellte Fragen betreffen die Sprache, nicht Regeln auf anderen Internetseiten.

Comment: Der erste Satz lautet: »Anführungszeichen sind Satzzeichen, die am Anfang und am Ende der direkten Rede, eines wörtlichen Zitats oder des zitierten Titels oder Namens eines Werkes stehen.« Ich lese da nichts über andere Arten der Auszeichnung. — *nicht Regeln auf anderen Internetseiten* – das andere Werk auf das ich mich beziehe ist nicht irgendeine Internetseite, sondern die offiziellen Rechtschreibregeln, also die höchste Instanz bzgl. der Zeichensetzung in der deutschen Sprache.

Comment: Genau: Zitat: wird English nun zitiert oder nur verwendet? "Regeln auf anderen Internetseiten" von mir bezog sich auf Wikipedia, sofern mir der Erstkommentar verständlich war. Bitte eigenen (Erst)Kommentar nochmal lesen und ggf. löschen+neuschreiben.

Comment: *Genau: Zitat: wird English nun zitiert oder nur verwendet?* – Es wird ziemlich klar nicht zitiert. Es geht nicht darum, exakt wiederzugeben, was jemand anderes gesagt hat. So oder so, der Wikipedia-Satz stellt keine Behauptung auf, dass sie in irgendeinem Kontext verwendet werden müssen.

Comment: *"Regeln auf anderen Internetseiten" von mir bezog sich auf Wikipedia, sofern mir der Erstkommentar verständlich war.* – Okay, wir reden anscheinend aneinander vorbei, also nochmal von vorne: »Wikipedia ist da gleich im ersten Satz sehr eindeutig« liest sich für mich so, als würdest Du Wikipedia als Beleg des vorangegangen Satzes angeben. Wenn nicht, dann stelle bitte klar, was Wikipedia Deines Erachtens behauptet oder belegt. Ich bin mir da nämlich immer noch nicht sicher.